# Google Translate within bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-translate

I use the site a lot but it is my first question:

I would like to get the Google translate plugin to work within a popover or modal window.  Can anyone help?

I have added a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Ld9qjrnq/19/

Google code:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'ar,bn,de,el,es,fr,hi,it,iw,ja,no,pa,zh-CN,zh-TW', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

I have been unsuccessful in putting this in a popover.

Answer (score 0):

the src doesn't work. 
You must alter the src for src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit". So the code will go work correctly.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - this src is the code directly provided by google.